# Split and map original values to different pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to map a function that splits names with the help of the `nameparser` package in python.

The function I use is the following:

```
def extract_parts(name):
    first, middle, last = (HumanName(name)).first,(HumanName(name)).middle, (HumanName(name)).last
    return first, middle, last
```

And the dataframe would be like the following for example with the `NAMES` column that contains the names that need to be split with the `nameparser` package.

```
ID | NAMES                    | column
1  | Ben Jerry                | I
2  | John Jack Joe            | I 
3  | Dr. Amelia von Lugenwitz | I
4  | Cristian Maria de Angel  | I
5  | The CBA Company          | C
6  | FBPTQ                    | C
```

And I loop the function and try to map it, but it only returns the last value. I guess it makes sense. But `.apply()` did not work, or I don't know how to apply it properly.

```
for index in range(len(file)):
    if file["column"][index] == "A":
        try:
            file["COLUMN1"], file["COLUMN2"], file["COLUMN3"] = extract_parts(file["ORIGINAL"][index])
        except TypeError as e:
            print(e)
```

And it should return a dataframe:

```
ID | COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3
1  | Ben     |         | Jerry
2  | John    | Jack    | Joe
3  | Amelia  |         | von Lugenwitz
4  | Cristian| Maria   | de Angel
```

Whereby `COLUMN1` represent the First name that is extracted by nameparser HumanName(), `COLUMN2` the Middle Names and `COLUMN3` the Last name.

Comment: Please share how are the names stored. A `DataFrame`?

Comment: Yes, I have added that they are stored in a Pandas column

Comment: @yatu that is what the function extract parts do

Comment: I believe the name_parser take a guess and leave one of the two empty

Comment: the nameparser would know what the first and last name is. You can try it out yatu..

Comment: What is `file`, the dataframe?

Comment: Yes, that's the dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe has a `names` column, for example:

```
                      names
0                 Ben Jerry
1             John Jack Joe
2  Dr. Amelia von Lugenwitz
3   Cristian Maria de Angel
```

You could use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to unpack the values into multiple columns:

```
df['first'], df['middle'], df['last'] = zip(*df['names'].apply(extract_parts))
```

Comment: Do I use this in the for loop instead of what I have after the try statement? Would I do something with the index also?

Comment: No need to use a `for` loop. Just do the line above one-time, change `df` to the name of your dataframe

Comment: Doesn't work. You didn't take into account the if statement, so I get the following error: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`. And when I use a try-except, it doesn't create the columns

Comment: @mrPy It will be better if you add a full example on your question, I mean a small sample of your original dataframe

Comment: @mrPy You have `if file["column"][index] == "A"` what is the relation with the "names" column?